# Converting daily temperature data to monthly and seasonal using R or Python

Tags: python, r

I have about 8 years worth of daily temperature data which I want to convert firstly into monthly, and then into seasonal data (sample below)

```
X    date      maxtp
1   20-Aug-07   19.1
2   21-Aug-07   17.6
3   22-Aug-07   21.8
4   23-Aug-07   20.0
5   24-Aug-07   22.4
6   25-Aug-07   21.2
7   26-Aug-07   19.3
8   27-Aug-07   17.5
9   28-Aug-07   18.9
10  29-Aug-07   18.3
11  30-Aug-07   19.5
```

Essentially I want the observed series to be separated into four sub-series containing 3 month blocks of the same season (winter, spring, summer, autumn).

Each block should consist of daily temperature values (I don't want monthly mean values etc.)

I'd really appreciate some help as I've been stuck for quite some time.

EDIT: Solution using R:

```
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
#splitting into new variables
year = as.numeric(format(data$date,"%Y"))
month = as.numeric(format(data$date,"%m"))
day = as.numeric(format(data$date,"%d"))

#new dataframe containing these variables and temp data
data <- data.frame(day,month,year,data$maxtp)

#Add 2 extra colums for Season.Year and Season
data <- cbind(data,NA,NA) # NA,NA adds two blank columns to existing csv file
colnames(data) <- c("Day","Month","Year","maxtp","Season.Year","Season") # names them

# Season.Year
data[ ,5] <- ifelse(data[,2] == 12, data[,3]+1, data[,3])    # in column 5, function says: if month = 12 (i.e. dec) then put year + 1, if not keep year

#defines months into seasons, W,SP,SU,A. puts output on column 6
data[,6][data[,2]=="12"|data[,2]=="1"|data[,2]=="2"] <- "W"
data[,6][data[,2]=="3"|data[,2]=="4"|data[,2]=="5"] <- "SP"
data[,6][data[,2]=="6"|data[,2]=="7"|data[,2]=="8"] <- "SU"
data[,6][data[,2]=="9"|data[,2]=="10"|data[,2]=="11"] <- "A"
```

Comment: What have you been stuck on?

Comment: @Elizion I've tried using this method http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/hydroTSM/dm2seasonal.html which only gives me average values and doesn't actually split up the series

Answer (score 2):

first define a mapping of months to

```
months2season = {
       12:0,1:0,2:0, #Dec/Jan/Feb are all winter (season 0)
       3:1,4:1,5:1, #Mar/Apr/May are all spring (season 1)
       6:2,7:2,8:2, #Jun/Jul/Aug are all summer (season 2)
       9:3,10:3,11:3 #sept/oct/nov are all fall (season 3)
}
```

now make a list of lists (one list for each season)

```
readings_by_season = [[],[],[],[]]
```

now you need to open your file and read it in placing each value in its season

```
import dateutil.parser as p
fh = open("my_text_file.csv")
headers = next(fh).split() #skip the header line
for data in fh:
    data = dict(zip(headers,data.split()))
    data["date"] =  p.parse(data["date"])
    #put it in the right bin
    season_id = months2seasons[data["date"].month]
    readings_by_season[season_id].append(data)
```

now you should have `readings_by_season` populated

```
winter,spring,summer,fall = readings_by_season
print winter
```

(this is an oversimplification that splits seasons evenly on month starts ... it gets a little more complicated to use breaks that occure mid month)

Answer (score -2):

Usually what you'd want to do is convert your data to data that you can actually use, so store this in a database, in a file you can access somewhere or use whatever it is in now. Basically create a data model.

Next you want to present the processed data you have in a way, so maybe you want a gui or just some text somewhere (database, terminal or file?)

Depending on how you want to present your data you will need some logic to get the data, process it and then output it.

I think in this case your question is not very specific and it seems like you don't know where to start. I hope you can move on with this answer and that the next steps will only need a few google searches.

Comment: This answer is beyond vague. Far far beyond vague.

Comment: It seems in line with the question to me.

Comment: This question is obviously pretty poor as it is not code-specific, but it is asking about separating temperature data into seasonal blocks with their daily values.  Then essentially your answer is to 1. Put your data into a usable form 2. Find logic to present your data 3. Present your data 4. Use Google searches. That is hardly succinct.

Comment: What I am trying to do is give some handles for @Pad to start with. Seperating them does not seems to be the problem to me, it's rather how to translate the solution into code. Introducing some seperation of concerns and better defining the situation and goal is the only thing one can do if all you have is the question asked here.